# ZooKepper Unable to start AdminServer, exiting abnormally

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I'm using apache-zookeeper-3.5.5 and I want to run zkServer but I get the below error:

When I run the zkServer failed to bind to 8080 port.

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to /0.0.0.0:8080
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:396)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.admin.JettyAdminServer.start(JettyAdminServer.java:103)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:342)
        ... 12 more
Unable to start AdminServer, exiting abnormally
```

My zoo.cfg file in like here:

```
tickTime=2000
# The number of ticks that the initial 
# synchronization phase can take
initLimit=10
# The number of ticks that can pass between 
# sending a request and getting an acknowledgement
syncLimit=5
# the directory where the snapshot is stored.
# do not use /tmp for storage, /tmp here is just 
# example sakes.
dataDir=/data
# the port at which the clients will connect
clientPort=2181
# the maximum number of client connections.
# increase this if you need to handle more clients
#maxClientCnxns=60
#
# Be sure to read the maintenance section of the 
# administrator guide before turning on autopurge.
#
# http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/current/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_maintenance
#
# The number of snapshots to retain in dataDir
#autopurge.snapRetainCount=3
# Purge task interval in hours
# Set to "0" to disable auto purge feature
#autopurge.purgeInterval=1
```

I don't know what is my problem?

Comment: This command will help `lsof -i :8080` if your OS is Unix based. Kill the PID that you get in output after you verify is not needed.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem is that the port 8080 is probably used by other application on your host (use `netstat` to check the opened ports).

To fix the issue use the property `admin.serverPort` in the "zoo.cfg" file to set any different port: **`admin.serverPort=8081`** but be sure that the port 8081 in the example is not used.

Comment: ideally the line "admin.serverPort" was not given, I had to add it but after adding it fixed issue for me.